# Problems with PHP/HTML contact form

Tags: php, html

I made contact form, so when i enter all info and click "Send" mail isn't send, he download file like on this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O53Lk.png) . Does someone know what is the point.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
        $email = $_POST['email']; 
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $to = "test@testemail.com"; 
        $subject = "New Message!"; 
        $body = "This is an automated message. Please do not reply to this email. \n\n $email \n\n $message";

        mail($to, $subject, $body); echo "Message Sent."; 
    }
    ?>



    <form id="contact-me-form" action="contact.php" name="contact_form "method="post">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Your Message Here"></textarea>
        <input id="sendEmail" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
```

Comment: Looks like your server is probably not configured to send files ending in `.php` through the PHP parser yet.

Comment: how to configure that, i use firebase... do you know?